# Fast replacement for JComboBox / BasicComboBoxUI?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've got a `JComboBox` that potentially can have thousands of items. They're sorted, and there's find-as-you-type, so in principle it's not completely unusable.

In practice, it's pretty unusable with just a couple of hundred items. I managed to improve the initial display performance using `setPrototypeDisplayValue()`, but `BasicListUI` still insists on configuring the list cell renderer for every item in the box (see `BasicListUI.updateLayoutState()`).

This, or something like it, is apparently a [known issue](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4762915) to Sun; it has been for going on eight years now, so I'm not holding my breath.

Short of implementing my own UI, has anyone got a workaround?

Comment: In my humble opinion, further than the performance, I would worry about the user experience. If you have potentially thousands of items in a combobox, maybe it's time to try to separate them in categories (and have a second combobox), or have another component to find your value. You have a "find as you type" approach already, maybe you should have a dedicated component which never displays the whole list, only a filtered view. It would also fix the performance issue.

Comment: @mcandre, if I wanted advice on my prose style I wouldn't have come to Stack Overflow. The same JComboBox potentially can have one item, or zero. A typical figure is ten. "Potentially can have" is not redundant, it's accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the hack that I came up with. The drawbacks are:

- if you want to maintain the look and feel, you have to separately subclass each `BasicComboBoxUI` extension you care about
- you have to use reflection to load your UI classes, since (for instance) a subclass of `WindowsComboBoxUI` won't load on Linux
- it won't work with L&Fs (e.g. MacOS?) that don't extend `BasicComboBoxUI`
- it makes assumptions about the `ListCellRenderer` that may not always be warranted

I'm still open to cleaner solutions.

```
class FastBasicComboBoxUI extends BasicComboBoxUI {
  @Override
  public void installUI(JComponent c) {
    super.installUI(c);

    Object prototypeValue = this.comboBox.getPrototypeDisplayValue();
    if (prototypeValue != null) {
      ListCellRenderer renderer = comboBox.getRenderer();
      Component rendererComponent = renderer
          .getListCellRendererComponent(this.listBox, 
              prototypeValue, 0, false, false);
      if (rendererComponent instanceof JLabel) {
        // Preferred size of the renderer itself is (-1,-1) at this point, 
        // so we need this hack
        Dimension prototypeSize = new JLabel(((JLabel) rendererComponent)
            .getText()).getPreferredSize();
        this.listBox.setFixedCellHeight(prototypeSize.height);
        this.listBox.setFixedCellWidth(prototypeSize.width);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm still open to cleaner solutions.

**Later**

Turns out this only solved some of the problems. Initial display of a combo box with a large number of items could still be really slow. I had to make sure the popup list box *immediately* gets a fixed cell size, by moving the code into the `ComboPopup` itself, as follows. Note that, as above, this depends on the prototype value.

```
@Override
protected ComboPopup createPopup() {
  return new BasicComboPopup(comboBox) {
    @Override
    protected JList createList() {
      JList list = super.createList();
      Object prototypeValue = comboBox.getPrototypeDisplayValue();
      if (prototypeValue != null) {
        ListCellRenderer renderer = comboBox.getRenderer();
        Component rendererComponent = renderer
            .getListCellRendererComponent(list, prototypeValue, 0, false, false);
        if (rendererComponent instanceof JLabel) {
          // Preferred size of the renderer itself is (-1,-1) at this point, 
          // so we need this hack
          Dimension prototypeSize = new JLabel(((JLabel) rendererComponent)
              .getText()).getPreferredSize();
          list.setFixedCellHeight(prototypeSize.height);
          list.setFixedCellWidth(prototypeSize.width);
        }
      }
      return list;
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`JList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) might be a better choice, as it uses a fly-weight approach to rendering and appears to support find-as-you-type.

If you use [`JComboBox`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html), add entries to the model *before* the component itself starts listening. This `SortedComboBoxModel` uses a simple [insertion sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) that is acceptable for a few thousand entries:

```
class SortedComboBoxModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel {

    /** Add elements by inserting in lexical order. */
    @Override
    public void addElement(Object element) {
        this.insertElementAt(element, 0);
    }

    /** Insert in lexical order by name; ignore index. */
    @Override
    public void insertElementAt(Object element, int index) {
        String name = element.toString();
        for (index = 0; index < this.getSize(); index++) {
            String s = getElementAt(index).toString();
            if (s.compareTo(name) > 0) {
                break;
            }
        }
        super.insertElementAt(element, index);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not really the issue -- the model's fully constructed before the combo box exists, and changes to it are all-or-nothing.